# .nrow() method in C++ in Rcpp returning zeros

Tags: r, rcpp

With *Rcpp*, I've defined a matrix *M* in *C++*. Using `M.nrow()`, we should be able to retrieve the number of rows. However, when I tried to return the number of rows as an `IntegerVector`, the answer is incorrect:

```
set.seed(1100)
M = matrix(sample(18), nrow = 6)
Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector tccp5(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}')
tccp5(M)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The correct answer should be the number of rows, e.g.

```
# [1] 6
```

Can you please explain what is happening?

Comment: If you change the type declaration of the function to `int` you'll get the correct output, e.g. `cppFunction('int tccp6(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}')`

Comment: @gfgm Looks like you've got a great answer there

Comment: @duckmayr you're too kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @gfgm's answer is spot on, I wanted to expand upon *why* declaring as an `int` and not `IntegerVector` leads to the right construction...

In particular, each *return* into *R* is seamlessly converted using `wrap()` to an [`SEXP`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs), or an *S* expression that points to the structure. By supplying `IntegerVector` and returning an `int`, the `wrap()` must instantiate a new `IntegerVector` of length `x` as there is no `SEXP` underlying an `int`. On the other hand, when the defined return type is `int`, the `wrap()` feature of *Rcpp* is able to correctly coerce the `int` into an `IntegerVector`.

---

To emphasize the underlying "seamless" transition that happens, let's add the parameter `verbose = TRUE` to `cppFunction()` to view how the *C++* code is: compiled, linked, and imported into *R*. (Note: I've truncated the output to the compilations.)

If we consider:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector tccp5(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}',
                  verbose = TRUE)
```

We get:

```
Generated code for function definition: 
--------------------------------------------------------

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector tccp5(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}

Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>
// tccp5
IntegerVector tccp5(IntegerMatrix M);
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_7_tccp5(SEXP MSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< IntegerMatrix >::type M(MSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(tccp5(M));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

Compared to:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('int tccp5(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}', 
                  verbose = TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
Generated code for function definition: 
--------------------------------------------------------

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int tccp5(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}

Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>
// tccp5
int tccp5(IntegerMatrix M);
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_9_tccp5(SEXP MSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< IntegerMatrix >::type M(MSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(tccp5(M));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The anomalous output arises because of the type declaration of the function.

```r
library(Rcpp)
M <- matrix(sample(1:18), nrow=6)

cppFunction('int tccp6(IntegerMatrix M) { int x = M.nrow(); return x;}')
tccp6(M)
#> [1] 6
```

Created on 2018-03-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).